# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdarg.h': No such file or directory make: *** [sqlite3.o]

Tags: c, windows, sqlite, makefile, gnu-make

I am to use **[GNU MAKE](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)** to make object file.

**filename** : **Makefile.vc08**

```
DBCRYPTO = ../dbcrypto
SQLCRYPT = ../sqlcrypt
TOP = $(SQLCRYPT)

PLATFORMSDKDIR="C:/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ SDKs/Windows/v6.0A"
VCTOOLKITINSTALLDIR=C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 9.0/VC
PREFIX=C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 9.0/VC

CL=$(PREFIX)/bin/cl.exe
CLFLAGS=-nologo
LINK=$(PREFIX)/bin/link.exe
INCINST=$(PREFIX)/include
LIBINST=$(PREFIX)/lib
BININST=$(PREFIX)/bin

CFLAGS+= $(CLFLAGS) -DNDEBUG=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLCRYPT3 -DSQLCRYPT3_HOBBLED -DSQLCRYPT3_HOBBLED_EVAL
CFLAGS+= -I$(TOP) -I$(DBCRYPTO) 

XLIB=$(PLATFORMSDKDIR)/lib
LFLAGS=$(XLIB)/uuid.lib $(XLIB)/kernel32.lib

SQLCRYPTOBJ+= aescrypt.o aeskey.o aestab.o \
         fileenc.o hmac.o prng.o pwd2key.o sha1.o \
         pkv.o

LIBOBJ+= sqlite3.o $(SQLCRYPTOBJ)

SHELLOBJ= shell.o

all: sqlcrypt3_static.lib sqlcrypt3.exe sqlcrypt3.dll

clean:
    rm -f *.dll *.lib *.exp *.exe *.o

sqlcrypt3_static.lib: $(LIBOBJ)
    $(LINK) -LIB -OUT:sqlcrypt3_static.lib $(LIBOBJ)

sqlcrypt3.exe: $(LIBOBJ) $(SHELLOBJ)
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -OUT:sqlcrypt3.exe $(LIBOBJ) $(SHELLOBJ)

sqlcrypt3.dll: $(LIBOBJ)
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -OUT:sqlcrypt3.dll -dll -def:sqlcrypt3.def $(LIBOBJ)

shell.o:    
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(SQLCRYPT)/shell.c

sqlite3.o:  
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(SQLCRYPT)/sqlite3.c

aescrypt.o: $(DBCRYPTO)/aescrypt.c $(DBCRYPTOHDR)
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(DBCRYPTO)/aescrypt.c

aeskey.o:   $(DBCRYPTO)/aeskey.c $(DBCRYPTOHDR)
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(DBCRYPTO)/aeskey.c

aestab.o:   $(DBCRYPTO)/aestab.c $(DBCRYPTOHDR)
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(DBCRYPTO)/aestab.c

fileenc.o:  $(DBCRYPTO)/fileenc.c $(DBCRYPTOHDR)
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(DBCRYPTO)/fileenc.c

hmac.o: $(DBCRYPTO)/hmac.c $(DBCRYPTOHDR)
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(DBCRYPTO)/hmac.c

prng.o: $(DBCRYPTO)/prng.c $(DBCRYPTOHDR)
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(DBCRYPTO)/prng.c

pwd2key.o:  $(DBCRYPTO)/pwd2key.c $(DBCRYPTOHDR)
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(DBCRYPTO)/pwd2key.c

sha1.o: $(DBCRYPTO)/sha1.c $(DBCRYPTOHDR)
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(DBCRYPTO)/sha1.c

pkv.o:  $(SQLCRYPT)/pkv.c $(SQLCRYPTHDR)
    $(CL) -c $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ $(SQLCRYPT)/pkv.c
```

First I install GNUMAKE in windows.
then set environment path of gnumake's make.exe.

then i am going to build command in cmd
command : **make -f Makefile.vc08**

it get error.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Do you understand the Makefile's content? The idea(s) behind it and how all this works?

Comment: Why aren't you using NMAKE? Where did you get that Makefile from?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but with electron-forge and sqlite3, after installing the sqlite3 and starting the server.